# Vim, search in document header

Tags: search, vim

I need a macro/function that searches the current document, starting at the top, for a specific pattern. Stopping at the first line that isn't commented out.

For example in this vim script:

```
"This is the first line

"This is the third line

if exists("did_something")
```

It would stop at if line, return true if it found the pattern and false otherwise.

All help appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify: do you mean "stopping at the first match that isn't  commented out"? Or do you ONLY want to search the first uncommented line?

Comment: @PrinceGoulash: he means searching in the header, which is the commented region at the top of the file, up until (and naturally excluding) the first non-commented line.

Comment: By the way, @Filip, the reason you're getting downvotes is because you're asking for a function with no indication of having tried anything. Stack Overflow is not here to provide you with code but to help you with code problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your pattern is the letter 'e'.

To search for a line that is not commented out, but contains an e:

```
 /^\%(\s*"\)\@!.*e
```

This uses a negative lookahead (`\@!`) to confirm that the start of the line (`^`) isn't followed by a the beginning of a comment (whitespace and then a double quote `\s*"`) but is followed by an 'e' (`.*e`).  The `\%(` and `\)` makes the enclosed pattern an atom that other operators (like negative lookahead) can operate on as a unit.

To run a command on matching lines, use `:g`

```
 :g/^\%(\s*"\)\@!.*e/echo "found one"
```

To see if the current line matches, use `match()`

```
 :echo match( getline(line('.')), '^\%(\s*"\)\@!.*e' ) >= 0 ? 'true' : 'false'
```

The regex is pretty much always the same, the question is what do you want to do with matching lines?